# How to round up the percentage values in google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am used Google pie chart in my web page.

I get Some percentage value like **89.8%**. I want to convert this percentage to **90%**. How can I round the values? Please help

Comment: The code that you given does not match your question.

Comment: Sorry @ Rajaprabhu. I have removed my code. My values came from database.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var value="89.8%";
var percentage=(Math.round(parseFloat(value)));
percentage=percentage+"%";
console.log(percentage);
```

Comment: plz see the location. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?hl=pt-BR

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 var s = "89.8%";
 s = s.split("%");
 s = Math.round(s[0]));
 s = s + "%";
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J4V5C/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the formatted value for all of your data points to the rounded values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    var val = data.getValue(i, 1);
    data.setFormattedValue(i, 1, Math.round(val).toString());
}
```

The chart will draw with the non-rounded values for accuracy, but display the rounded values in tooltips.